# How does Else-If work when separated by a newline?

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

I have an AutoHotkey script which includes a strange block of else-if statements:

```
if (x=1)
{
    ; ...
}
else
if (y=8)
{
    ; ...
}
```

[Based on the documentation for if statements](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm), I can think of two ways to interpret this:

---

1) An `else-if` statement:

```
if (x=1)
{
    ; ...
}
else if (y=8)
{
    ; ...
}
```

2) An `if` statement inside an `else` block

```
if (x=1)
{
    ; ...
}
else
{
    if (y=8)
    {
        ; ...
    }
}
```

---

**What is the behavior when `else` and `if` are separated by newlines?**

Comment: Or a very quick test could offer a third alternative, which is that the newline is irrelevant. Copy/paste the exact code you have into a new text file, add `x := 1` at the top, insert a `MsgBox` at the lines you have `...`, and run the script. Then change to `x := 8` and run again. Now remove the newline and repeat both tests. Now change `x := 10`  (so that neither condition applies), and repeat the two tests. What does that show you?

Comment: All three of your code snippets are equivalent. `else` is always followed by a conditional block.  A conditional block is either a single statement or multiple statements wrapped by curly braces. Any and all newlines following `else` are irrelevant.

Comment: @JimU Can you post that as an answer?